# What is wrong with my code? Error expected identifier or '('

Tags: c, cs50

This is an interesting code basically I'm trying to do that silly thing where you ask someone their name and then ask them to spell it. If they spell out it then you tell them that you actually spell it (what they put in as their name) and vice versa. I get an error at line 7:1 so the first curly bracket. It's the error expected identifier or '('. Thanks so much for your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

string it(void);
int main(void);

{
    do 
    {
        printf("What's your name? ");
        string name = get_string();
    }

    while (name = NULL)

   do
   {
        printf("How do you spell it?");
        string spelling = get_string();
   }

   while (spelling = NULL)

   if (name = spelling)
    {
        printf("No it's spelled 'it'.");
    }

    else if (spelling = it)
    {
        printf("No it's spelled %s",name);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("That's wrong on so many levels.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the stray semicolon after `int main(void)`.

Comment: `do{ ... }while(..)` add `;`. and `spelling = NULL` --> `spelling == NULL`

Comment: Also `while (name = NULL)` --> `while (name == NULL);`

Comment: Declare `name` and `spelling` in outside do-while-loop.

Comment: `spelling = it` Unknown what you want to do. You maybe looking for [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: Thank you all for your help! :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you compile with strict warnings and not get any?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove semicolon (;) from `int main(void);`

Putting a `;` makes it a function prototype and here it is a function definition.

A Statement like `return_type fun_name(arguments);` implies that it is a function prototype and you have written the definition later in the code.

While statement like this (without semicolon)

```
return_type fun_name(arguments)
{
  //body
}
```

implies that the code following this `return_type fun_name(arguments)` is the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the ";" after int main(void) in Line 5
Erasing it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colon(;) after int main(void) and add it after while()